# In which comic is The Flash sent flying into space after slipping on an atomic banana peel?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, the-flash

Earlier today I was alerted to the existence of this scene from a Silver Age-era Flash story:

[image]

(FYI, Flash: *nothing* is impossible in comic books.)

This scene appears to be quite (in)famous, turning up dozens of results on Google, but none of them give a source for the original comic. Nor do they state what happened next, which is especially interesting given that other questions on this site indicate that The Flash [cannot move](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143200/how-does-the-flash-move-through-space) [or breathe in space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72457/can-the-flash-breathe-in-outer-space).

**When did this happen?**

Comment: Nothing is impossible... except sane scenarios.

Comment: This is why I don't read comics.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [Comicvine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/justice-league-of-america-154-ill-kill-you-in-your/4000-18469/), this is *Justice League of America* [#154](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_League_of_America_Vol_1_154) from May 1978, subtitled "I'll Kill You In Your Dreams!". You can read it [here](http://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Justice-League-of-America-1960/Issue-154?id=27580#21).

[image]

In the story, Doctor Destiny sent the Justice League dreams with a warning about how they will be taken down, and sent their respective enemies instructions (in dreams) on how to take the heroes down. The Trickster was sent a dream where he made Flash trip on the atomic banana. The Flash, in turn, was sent a dream where he tripped on it.

[image]
 <sub>Click for full resolution</sub>

He then uses a gravitational assist around Jupiter to come back to Earth, because why not?

[image]
 <sub>Click for full resolution</sub>

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: And note, too, that this is very firmly *not* a Silver Age story.

Comment: @PatrickWynne This comic series started in 1960, so that may be the reason people call it a Silver Age story.